# Getting a count of correct and incorrect test attempts

Tags: sql

I need to get a count of correct and incorrect attempts per testID:

```
select
    AttempID,
    Test_ID,
    Date,
    SubjectID,
    Date,
    sum(Correct) as Correct,
    sum(InCorrect) as InCorrect 
from tbldemo
group by
    AttempID,
    Test_ID,
    Date,
    SubjectID_name,
    Date
```

Do I need to `group by` each column other column, and then sum over `Correct` and `Incorrect`? `AttempID`, `Test ID`, `date` and `subject ID` combinations will remain constant.

> ```
>   AttempID  Test ID   Date      Subject ID  Correct  Incorrect  
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          0       1
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          0       1
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          1       0
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          0       1
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          1       0
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          0       1
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          1       0
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          1       0
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          0       1
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          1       0
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          0       1
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          0       1
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          0       1
>    1          2      2014-05-12     2          0       1
>    3          4      2014-05-12     2          0       1
>    3          4      2014-05-12     2          1       0
>    3          4      2014-05-12     2          1       0
>    3          4      2014-05-12     2          0       1
>    3          4      2014-05-12     2          0       1
>    3          4      2014-05-12     2          0       1
>    3          4      2014-05-12     2          1       0
> ```

Comment: I've edited your question to what I believe you were asking; if you feel I've missed your intent, please let us know!

Comment: @JvR Thank You for giving your time !!! :)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the second `Date` in your select or grouping.  Other than that, the query itself looks fine.

I'm a bit more worried about how your table is built, though.

- There appear to be duplicate records.  How would you go about selecting a specific record?
- `Correct` and `Incorrect` are [functionally dependent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency): if one has 0, the other must have 1.

If you have control over the structure of this table, you may want to look into [normalising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) it.